# How to remove this iptables rule?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I have an iptables rule. When searching for it with

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

I am getting it

```
Chain tcp_inbound (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
xxxx
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.10.0.20           0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
xxxx
...
```

My goal is to delete this rule.

I tried with

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT 2
```

But the rule is still there. I am on debian. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to find which rule to delete is to check the output of `iptables-save`, and change `-A` to `-D` is the rule you want to remove.

In your case :

```
$ iptables-save | grep 10.10.0.20
....
-A tcp_inbound -s 10.10.0.20/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
....
```

So you just need to issue :

```
iptables -D tcp_inbound -s 10.10.0.20/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Excellent answer, this saved me a lot of time, thank you so much.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to delete rule 2 of chain `INPUT`, where your rule is stored in chain `tcp_inbound`.